# Bootstrap: .form-control:before won't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to style an form control over CSS (example http://jsfiddle.net/fyVs4/).

But the CSS selector `.form-control:before` won't work- Curiouse, i had make a other button with CSS ober `button:before` and that's work:

**Won't work**

```
.form-control:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 42px;
    background: #00122A url('../images/button/left.png');
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

**WORK**

```
nav ul li button:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 37px;
    background: #00122A url('../images/button/left.png');
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like input fields cannot have pseudo elements, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Aww, really? Thats bad. Okay, otherwise i must use an container. Big Thanks!